# Extract boolean properly in from array sent by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my form I have several fields with string data and one with boolean.
    appointment (string)
    customer (string)
    manage_mode (boolean)

In  JS I am collecting my form data to send to php via AJAX with this:

```
    var formData = jQuery.parseJSON($('input[name="post_data"]').val());
```

If manage mode is false, If I check this in the console, this sends out by AJAX all the string data and I see -- `"manage_mode":false` 
            which is expected

At the php side I have try to extract the data  with this:

```
        $appointment = $post_data['appointment'];
        $customer = $post_data['customer'];
        $manage_mode = $post_data['manage_mode'];
```

All the string data in appointment and customer is processed properly and I am able to use it as expected.  But boolean is not functioning properly.  False is read as true.  Do I have to handle it differently on the php end?

I am supposing that on the PHP side the boolean is being seen as a string because it is processed as true regardless. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on PHP and check what value is beeing passed, post it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am supposing that on the PHP side the boolean is being seen as a string because it is processed as true regardless.

Sure it's so!
And the very simple solution is to translate `true`|`false` strings into `TRUE`|`FALSE` boolean values:

```
$manage_mode = $post_data['manage_mode'] == 'true' ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

In case you're not absolutely sure of what comes from your JSON source you may be more secure, like this:

```
switch ($post_data['manage_mode']) {
  case 'true': $manage_mode = TRUE; break;
  case 'false': $manage_mode = FALSE; break;
  default:
    // depends on what better matches your needs outside of this:
    // . simply FALSE
    // . FALSE and throw an error
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    `alert(formData.manage_mode);`

The formData should be an Object that you can access info accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$manage_mode = filter_var ($post_data['manage_mode'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```